# Passing jquery variable as an argument to scala function

Tags: jquery, scala, playframework-2.0, apache-spark

I am working on an application in which front end side is HTML and jquery. I am using spark and scala for my backend side processing to bring the data at various levels. Consider a situation where i want to pass date in a jquery variable to scala and display the results on HTML after processing.

By googling i found out play framework. Will it help in my situation?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) requests.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely NOT possible like that - your scala view is rendered on the **server-side** long before the HTML and jQuery is displayed to the user on the **client-side**.

Anyway this is task for jQuery (or maybe better some JS framework like Angular) to manipulate your HTML directly in the browser without refreshing whole code from the server. Of course most probably you'll want to send an AJAX request to the server in the background to persist changed data to the DB, but here I'm just shooting.